Can't paste the Text copied from the PDF
I wanted to make notes out of some documents. Hence wanted to copy some sentences, but whenever I copy and paste them, the text is replaced by Question Marks.
Example:
In a federal polity, SC verdict granting state power to tax mining
Output:
�� � �������������� �� ������� ������������������� �� ���������

I have seen something like this occur when the document uses embedded fonts and a nonstandard encoding.  I don't have a solution but that may at least be the direction to look.

Can you give a link to such an article, so others can see that issue?

What are you pasting into? Some programs might handle the clipboard differently. You can try Paste Special (CTRL+ALT+V) to see if there are different formats on the Clipboard.

I would also check to see if the PDF document has a security setting that prevents copying text. Looks in the File menu, Properties, Security tab. Look for "Content Copying: Allowed" (or not)
